# Random Image Generator Android

Tags: android, eclipse, image, random, generator

I am working with Android in Eclipse. I have my random Image generator working. At this moment when the page is loaded there's a random image loaded in ImageView1 automatically before the user clicks the button. (after the user clicks the button another random image is loaded). 
***When the page is loaded I don't want any images to show on the ImageView1 until the user clicks the button. How may I be able to change my code so that no image is loaded automatically until the user clicks the button?**

```
    package com.senior.callacab2;

    import java.util.Random;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Generatedrinks extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


private int[] mPhotoIds = new int [] { R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7 };

private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

private ImageView iv;

// Makes new images appear after every button click
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.generatedrinks);

    Integer q = mPhotoIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mPhotoIds.length)];
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageResource(q);

    View nextButton = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:

 iv.setImageResource(mPhotoIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mPhotoIds.length)]);
        break;
    }

    // Makes button2 invisible after two clicks the first click generates a
    // random image and the second click makes the button disappear
    Button generator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    generator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    // When this button is pressed it takes the user to the next layout
    // called Scoreclass.class

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Scorecard.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });

}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want the activity to load the image before you click, then don't load the image when you start the activity...

You have this code in your `onCreate`:

```
Integer q = mPhotoIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mPhotoIds.length)];
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setImageResource(q);
```

Remove the first and third lines (the second one is still useful to find the view for later use) and you won't load an image when your activity starts.

Comment: Glad to help. If this answers your question to your satisfaction, you can click the check mark next to this answer to mark it as an accepted answer.